# Octave: invalid use of script in index expression in exp function

Tags: matlab, octave

I am using Octave. I wrote this simple script with name example1.m:

```
 t = [0:0.01:5];
 x2 = exp(-3*t);
 plot(t,x2);
```

I am waiting for the plot, but I get this error:

> Octave: invalid use of script in index expression in exp function

This script works with other default functions like abs, log, etc. and it worked in the past with the exp function. But now it's not.
What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have a script named `t.m` on your path?

Comment: No, i dont have!

Comment: Hm, what about `exp.m`. ;)

Comment: it seems that you have a variable named `exp` in your workspace

Comment: what if you type the command 'whos' ?

Comment: What is the output of `which exp`, and of `version` ?

Comment: Loving the nickname btw! Tasty soup, that is!